# Removing specific characters from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file which seems to have several values which have junk data that look like: ÂÂ‡_Â¤Ã‹Ã§Ã©Ã¨_Â…

I have imported the file into a pandas dataframe. How can I get rid of these characters? I would like to delete the contents of the cell which have such characters and put in a flag value instead (something like -99999). The table has mixed data types.

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs
import unicodedata
import csv
import StringIO

testData = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', encoding="iso-8859-1", engine='python')
```

/*Using encoding utf-8 gives me an error about invalid start byte, using default engine doesn't work either.*/

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: Not sure. I got it as an excel csv. Is there a way to determine the encoding?

Comment: You could try using various "encoding guessers" out there.  But really encoding is something that you should be told when you are given a file (e.g., if you download it from somewhere, the place where you get it should mention what the encoding is).

Answer (score 1):

IF you know what characters you are willing to accept, you could use a regex to filter your values, something like:

```
testData['stringcol'].where(testData['stringcol'].str.contains('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]'), 
-999999)
```